# FTPS 431 Failed to setup secure session

Tags: ftps, iis-6

I try to connect to a FTPS site with WinSCP but it always returns back this error: **534 Policy requires SSL.** The certificate is in IIS 6.1, I use TLS\SSL Explicit encryption and passive mode in WinSCP.
Help me, please.

**Update**

WinSCP log:

> ```
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.000 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.000 WinSCP Version 5.11.3 (Build 7995) (OS 10.0.15063 - Windows 10 Enterprise)
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.000 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.001 Log level: Normal
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.001 Local account: XXX\hatvanis
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.001 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.001 Process ID: 24744
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.001 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Time zone: Current: GMT+1, Standard: GMT+1 (Közép-európai téli idő ), DST: GMT+2 (Közép-európai nyári idő ), DST Start: 2018. 03. 25., DST End: 2018. 10. 28.
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Login time: 2018. február 1., csütörtök 7:49:37
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Session name: ftp.test.com|FTP1\User1@ftp.test.com (Site)
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Host name: ftp.test.com (Port: 21)
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 User name: ftp.test.com|FTP1\User1 (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Transfer Protocol: FTP
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Disable Nagle: No
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Proxy: None
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Send buffer: 262144
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 UTF: Auto
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 FTPS: Explicit TLS/SSL [Client certificate: No]
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Session reuse: Yes
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 TLS/SSL versions: SSLv3-TLSv1.2
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.002 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.003 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.092 Connecting to ftp.test.com ...
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.092 Connected with ftp.test.com, negotiating TLS connection...
> < 2018-02-01 07:49:37.092 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> > 2018-02-01 07:49:37.092 AUTH TLS
> < 2018-02-01 07:49:37.092 431 Failed to setup secure session.
> > 2018-02-01 07:49:37.092 AUTH SSL
> < 2018-02-01 07:49:37.092 431 Failed to setup secure session.
> . 2018-02-01 07:49:37.093 Connection failed.
> * 2018-02-01 07:49:37.137 (EFatal) Connection failed.
> * 2018-02-01 07:49:37.137 Connection failed.
> * 2018-02-01 07:49:37.137 Failed to setup secure session.
> ```

Total Commander log:

> ```
> Using sChannel (Secur32.dll) for SSL/TLS connection.
>   Connect to: (2018.02.01 8:00:35)
>   hostname=ftp.test.com
>   username=ftp.test.com|FTP1\User1
>   startdir=
>   ftp.test.com=172.31.2.116
>   220 Microsoft FTP Service
>   AUTH TLS
>   431 Failed to setup secure session.
>   AUTH SSL
>   431 Failed to setup secure session.
>   QUIT
>   ----------
>   Connect to: (2018.02.01 8:00:37)
>   hostname=ftp.test.com
>   username=ftp.test.com|FTP1\User1
>   startdir=
>   ftp.test.com=172.31.2.116
>   220 Microsoft FTP Service
>   USER ftp.test.com|FTP1\User1
>   534 Policy requires SSL.
>   QUIT
> ```

Comment: Show us WinSCP session log file.

Comment: There's no *"534 Policy requires SSL"* in WinSCP log. Your question is misleading. There's only *"431 Failed to setup secure session"*. That's a completely different problem that what you claim. Correct your question.

Comment: Your question text still refers to 534.